# Hypernym for "clients", "members" and "partners"

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, hypernyms

We're building a feature for a website and trying to think of a hypernym for *clients*, *partners* and *members* so that the feature remains generic enough for re-use later on other websites.

Comment: Clients/partners/members of what?

Comment: @ElendilTheTall That would depend on who we're building the website for. A law firm, for example, might have clients and partners while a not-for-profit organization might have only members and no clients (per se). We're trying to avoid having to build a separate module for every different type of organization, hence the need for a generic term.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Stakeholders** would be the term.

[Stakeholders](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/stakeholder.html#ixzz2JRrnm0aY) : *A person, group or organization that has interest or concern in an organization. Some examples of key stakeholders are **creditors, directors, employees, government** (and its agencies), **owners** (shareholders), **suppliers, unions**, and the **community** from which the business draws its resources.*

Answer (score 3):

You might try *[stakeholders](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/stakeholder)*:-

> 1. (Economics, Accounting & Finance / Banking & Finance) a person or group owning a significant percentage of a company's shares
> 2. (Business / Industrial Relations & HR Terms) a person or group not owning shares in an enterprise but affected by or having an interest in its operations, such as the employees, customers, local community, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Less sophisticated than "stakeholders" is **associates**.

Associate: person joined with another or others in an enterprise, business, etc.; partner; colleague.

Comment: But a _client_ cannot be termed as an _associate_.

Answer (score 1):

Would generically referring to them as ***collaborators*** suffice?

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking about the word "organisations" but I'm not sure if it's generic enough.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to further abstract the function of the party, then ***entity*** is appropriate.  To be less abstract, Sayan's ***stakeholder*** will do, but this specifies that they have a real investment or "stake" in the project (material or otherwise).  Less specific than that is an ***associate***.