# One word that describes customer, business and vendor

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, hypernyms

Is there one word that can describe the following words?

> customer, business, and vendor.

I am working on a system, and I need to somehow fit all the above categories under one page. Currently, I have thought about putting them under "Entities", but this just doesn't sound right to me...

Comment: Related: [Hypernym for “clients”, “members” and “partners”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/102247/hypernym-for-clients-members-and-partners).

Comment: A "business" could be a general category (such as show business) or an activity ("we did a lot of business last quarter"). A "business" could also be either a customer or a vendor. What kind of business are we to deal with here?

Comment: I read 'business' in the sense of 'company', 'firm' or 'organisation'. If that's correct I am then guessing that the 'customer' and the 'vendor' are, respectively, a customer and supplier of the business. If this is the case I would support @alwayslearning's suggestion of 'party'. Otherwise I'm not too sure that the business would be a party.

Comment: Please provide a linguistic context for the word you're looking for. That is, how would it look in a sentence / paragraph / etc, not just as a heading?

Answer (score 7):

***Party*** ([MW dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/party)):

> 3:  a person or group participating in an action or affair
>
> *a mountain-climbing **party***
>
> *a **party** to the transaction*
>
> **Examples** of party in a sentence:
>
> the two parties in the marriage contract
>
> The parties in the lawsuit reached a settlement.

Answer (score 5):

**stakeholders**

Quoting [BBC for Schools](http://www.bbc.co.uk/schools/gcsebitesize/business/environment/stakeholders1.shtml) site:

> A **stakeholder** is anyone with an interest in a business.
>   Stakeholders are individuals, groups or organisation
>   that are affected by the activity of the business. They include:
>
> - **Owners** who are interested in how much profit the business makes.
> - **Managers** who are concerned about their salary.
> - **Workers** who want to earn high wages and keep their jobs.
> - **Customers** who want the business to produce quality products at reasonable prices.
> - **Suppliers** who want the business to continue to buy their products.
> - **Lenders** who want to be repaid on time and in full.
> - The **community** which has a stake in the business as employers of local people. [...].

Answer (score 1):

You could also try '**actor**'. It is formal but according to Merriam-Webster Collegiate Dictionary, 'actor' means '[...] 3: one that takes part in any affair'.

Or you could also try '**transactor**' – from 'transaction', which would include purchase/sale.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm writing a program that has services and clients to those services, represented as OO classes.  I've discovered that the two have enough in common that I should have a common base-class for both of them, but finding an appropriate descriptor has been challenging!  "Transactor" is the best I've discovered thus far.  Although some of their interaction is one-way messaging, some are actual transactions.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the term "Partner". Seems to classify all three terms as one.

Comment: Hi Ron.  Welcome to the site.  Thanks for taking the time out to answer.  Please consider expanding your answer with some further explanation such as an example sentence, or a citation with a source.

Answer (score -1):

If you're looking for an umbrella term that encompasses them all along with their various relationships - as opposed to a word that can refer to any of the three - then I'd suggest something like "business ecosystem" (or even just "ecosystem").

http://www.investopedia.com/terms/b/business-ecosystem.asp

Answer (score -1):

How about

**Transactional Level**

*Transactional*

> Relating to buying and selling [see
>   here](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/transactional)